no refresh token after successful login via Oauth with https url, but i do get refresh token on http://localhost
when i login from my localhost, "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirect}&response_type=token"
i get authenticated, and the callback includes the refresh_token. yay.
but when i login form mydomain.com, i get authenticated but the callback url has no refresh_token.
why?
setup
i have 1 salesforce connected app with 2 Callback URLs:

http://localhost:3000/auth/salesforce/callback
https://mydomain.com/auth/salesforce/callback

i enabled

Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)
refresh token valid until revoked.


Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.
